# What does >>= mean?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what >>= means (I thought greater than or equal to was >=) also what is: (times & 1) from below.

```
function repeat (string, times) {
var result = ''
while (times > 0) {
if (times & 1) result += string
times >>= 1
string += string
}
 return result
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's a bitwise operator, but then I don't get why the `=` is there... It's confusing even to me.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators a very useful resource

Comment: `times >>=1` is a short cut, same as `times = times >> 1`. Similar to the syntax of `a += b` (`a = a + b`).

Comment: The title of this question isn't very descriptive.

Comment: That's a lot of effort when `function repeat(string,times) {return new Array(times+1).join(string);}` would suffice...

Answer (score 5):

`>>=` is a right-shift-and-assign [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Right_shift_assignment). `>>= 1` is simply integer division by 2.

`&` is a Bitwise AND [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND). `time & 1` is simply checking if it is odd.

For more in-depth guide on *all* javascript operators, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators